# Extjs form populating with grid record

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I'm trying to get grid record data through loadRecord(record).
 Double clicking on record opens a new window. I want the record data to be displayed in the text field of form.

```
var fg1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Grid Selection',
        hieght: 500,
        width: 500,
        margin: 20,
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                itemId: 'grid1',
                selType: 'rowmodel',
                store: store,

                listeners: {
                    //afterrender: function(win) 
                    //{
                    handler: function (RowModel, record, index, eOpts) {
                        var u = this.getRecord();
                        u.applyToFields(record);


                        loadRecord(record);
                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    itemdblclick: function (view, record, htmlItem, index,
                        eventObject, opts) {

                        var win = new Ext.Window({
                                title: 'Entry Information',
                                id: 'myNewWindow',
                                rIx: 'rowIndex',
                                width: 400,
                                height: 400,
                                items: [{

                                    xtype: 'form',
                                    layout: 'fit',
                                    itemId: 'combo1',
                                    height: 400,
                                    closable: false,
                                    grow: true,
                                    closeAction: 'hide',
                                    autoHide: true,
                                    bodyPadding: 10,
                                    items: [{}]
                                });

                                win.show();
```

Comment: There's an example of exactly that: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#form-grid

Comment: There are missing braces and brackets in your code, check.